I cant see anything when i render my image
I'm a complete beginner to blender and I follow tutorials on YouTube so I don't understand what to do. I can't see anything, no light, no object (even though they're all there) just a shadow whenever I render my image. I've gone through a lot of posts but nothing is helping.
my object in the rendered mode is also really grainy and I don't understand what the cycles even are or where to find them to change them



Hello and welcome. I cannot see where the light object is in your viewport. Could it be that your monkey object is way very big and the light object is inside of it? Try a new file and render the default cube. Do you see the cube?

Sorry for the late reply. My light objects is there, its behind the camera actually. I tried it with the default cube but i got the same result when i rendered the image. there was still no light.

Have you tried resetting to factory settings, does the problem persist? If so then this is a bug and unfortunately off topic.
